# Event clicked in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem when clicked a row in a **UITableView**

I used this method **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** to catch when the user clicks on a row, but doesn't work normally. 
the user must press and hold the row to execute the action but do not want it to be so.

Any idea what may be happening?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   Refunds *current = [refunds_view objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   DetailRefundsViewController *myVC = (DetailRefundsViewController *)[storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailRefundsViewController"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: `delaysContentTouches`?

Comment: are there any controls which can prevent to call this method? It can be something with `UIGestureRecognizer`. Could you post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, your code is instantly work, just modify class name and Storyboard Identifier.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LJWDetailViewController *myVC = (LJWDetailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LJWDetailViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I think, some of your codes are block this didSelectRowAtIndexPath: Method.

find out which controls are block this method
and set those control's delaysContentTouches Property by NO like this.

```
_imageScroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

Sorry for Poor English :<

Answer (score 0):

If you're using StoryBoards, then I think you're better off using a push segue directly from the TableViewCell to the ViewController you want in the Interface Builder (control click and drag from the TableViewCell to the ViewController). Make sure to give the segue a name (in my case below "showDetail"). Then implement the code below:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }    
}
```